# Processes control, communication - kill next process and resume it

Tags: c, bash

I made a C program that calls bash script files .sh by using `system(" ");`, in this program the process father forks 3 processes (1. 2. 3.).
What I'd like to add to my program is:

- when the father forks the third process (3.) it does a "wait" ( `wait (&status);` )
- at this point the third process will be executing, but before executing it I want to use a script that gets the next (process 3.) process' PID in order to kill it.
- after that, the control returns to the father process (because its son has been killed), so the father has to restore the process 3. (that was previously killed) by using another script.sh!

That's it. How can I do these steps in bash and C, or one of them?

Summarizing, what I need to do is doing "processes concurrency"
I have to create processes that don't have to wait for other processes to finish, but they have to start meanwhile other processes make part of output available for them in order to use that output. In this way I will have "mutual communication" using "kill" bash command.

I hope it's clear! Are my steps good to implement that processes communication using kill command?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use the fork() function? http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html

Comment: Note that `system()` is synchronous; it does not return until the process it launches terminates.  This is going to complicate your system.  Also, note that plain `wait()` waits for a child to exit; any child.  You need to use `waitpid()` or a relative to wait for a specific process.  Your scenario is confusing; 'restoring process 3' doesn't make much sense.  If 3 has died, all you can do is run something instead, but it won't have the same PID as 3, etc.